# How to find Eigenfunction of this Sturm-Liouville problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems, sturm-liouville

***My question what do I have to do to find the eigenfunction in the first case***

It is given the following problem
\begin{align} 
xy''(x)+y'(x)+ \frac{\lambda}{x}y(x) &=0, & &x\in(1,e^{2\pi})  \tag1
\end{align}
With $y'(1)=y'(e^{2\pi})=0$

This is a Sturm-Liouville problem in the form
$$(xy'(x))'+\frac{\lambda}{x}y(x)=0 \tag2$$

where $p(x)=x, q(x)=0,r(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

Now we solve this problem for different values of $\lambda$.

1. **If $\lambda=0$**

Then the equation (1) becomes in the form
$$xy''(x)+y'(x)=0$$
This is an Euler-Cauchy equation with general solution
$$y(x)=c_1 \log(x)+c_2 \tag3$$
Now we differentiate the expression $(3)$ and we have
$$y'(x)=c_1 \frac{1}{x}$$

Then we plug in the initial conditions
$$y'(1)=0\Rightarrow c_1=0$$

2. **If $\lambda>0$** we write $k^2$ with $k>0$
   Then equation (1) becomes the form
   $$xy''(x)+y'(x)+ \frac{k^2}{x}y(x)=0$$

With general solution $$y(x)=c_1 \cos(k\log(x))+ c_2 \sin(k\log(x)) \tag 4$$
Now we differentiate the expression $(4)$ and we have
$$y'(x)=\frac{c_2 k \cos(k\log(x))-c_1 k \sin(k\log(x))}{x}$$
Then we plug in the initial conditions
$$y'(1)=0\Rightarrow c_2=0$$ so
$$y'(e^{2\pi})=0 \Rightarrow \frac{c_1 k \sin(k \log(e^{2 \pi}))}{e^{2 \pi}} =0$$
Where $k \neq 0$ and $c_1\neq 0$ because we are looking for no trivial solutions.
Thus,
$\sin(2\pi k)=0$ so $k=\frac{n}{2}, \ n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Then the eigenfunction is $$y(x)=c_1 \cos(\frac{n}{2} \log(x))$$

3. **If $\lambda<0$** we write $-k^2$ with $k>0$
   Then the equation (1) becomes in the form
   $$xy''(x)+y'(x)- \frac{k^2}{x}y(x)=0$$

With general solution $$y(x)=c_1 \cosh(k\log(x))+i c_2 \sinh(k\log(x)) \tag 5$$
Now we differentiate the expression $(5)$ and we have
$$y'(x)=\frac{c_2 k \cosh(k\log(x))+ c_1 k \sinh(k\log(x))}{x}$$
Then we plug in the initial conditions
$$y'(1)=0\Rightarrow i \ c_2 \ k=0 \Rightarrow c_2=0$$ so
$$y'(e^{2\pi})=0 \Rightarrow \frac{c_1 k \sinh(k \log(e^{2 \pi}))}{e^{2 \pi}} =0$$
Where $k \neq 0$ and $c_1\neq 0$, because we are looking for no trivial solutions.
Thus,
$\sinh(2\pi k)=0$ so $k=\frac{in}{2}, \ n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then the eigenfunction is $$y(x)=c_1 \cosh(\frac{in}{2} \log(x))$$

Comment: As eigenfunction in the first case you can choose $\;\log x\;$ ...or any other non-zero scalar multiple of it.

Comment: @DonAntonio    But $c_1=0$. How can I choose $\log(x)$?

Comment: I didn't see your whole work, but if you got $\;c_1=0\;$ then (1) how come you got $\;c_1\log x+c_2\;$ as the general solution instead of just $\;y(x)=c_2\;$ ? (2) in the second case you can choose $\;y(x)=1\;$ as the general solution in that case and thus eigenfuction, since, as you say, $\;c_1=0\;$ and I assume it does **not** have to be that $\;c_2=0\;$ too...

Comment: @DonAntonio If $\lambda=0$ then we have the function $x y''(x)+y'(x)=0$. This is an Euler-Cauchy equation with general solution $y(x)=c_1 \log(x)+c_2$ Then I defferentiate the general solution so $y'(x)=\frac{c_1}{x}$. Thus when I plug in the initial conditions the result is $c_1=0$

Comment: Fine, but then the general solution is just $\;c_2\;$ , right? Choose $\;y(x)=1\;$ as eigenfunction.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you very much! I got it!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Start by solving the following
$$
      xy''(x)+y'(x)+\frac{\lambda}{x}y(x)=0 \\
       y'(1)=0,\; y(1)=1.
$$
The reason for the added condition $y(1)=1$ is that it is always possible to multiply any solution without that equation by a non-zero factor that will result in $y(1)=1$, which this problem a unique solution. Furthermore, there is no loss in generality because, if $y(1)=0$, then $y\equiv 0$, and, otherwise, multiplying $y$ by a non-zero scale factor will result in a solution where $y(1)=1$.

As was noted, the following equation is an Euler equation:
$$
         x^2y''(x)+xy'(x)+\lambda y(x)=0
$$
So there is at least one solution of the form $u^{\alpha}$ where
$$
           \alpha(\alpha-1)+\alpha+\lambda = 0 \\
       \alpha^2+\lambda= 0 \\
         \alpha = \pm i\sqrt{\lambda}.
$$
Assuming a solution $y(x)=Ax^{-\alpha}+Bx^{\alpha}$, then the requirements that $y(1)=1$ and $y'(1)=0$ gives
$$
                   A+B=1 \\
                  (-A+B)\alpha=0.
$$
That gives $A=B=1/2$ and corresponding solution
$$
       y(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x^{\alpha}+x^{-\alpha})=\frac{1}{2}(x^{i\sqrt{\lambda}}+x^{-i\sqrt{\lambda}})=\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\ln x)
$$
This solution is an eigenfunction iff $y'(e^{2\pi})=0$, which results in the eigenvalue equation for $\lambda$:
$$
    \frac{\sqrt{\lambda}\sin(2\pi\sqrt{\lambda})}{e^{2\pi}}=0
  \implies \sqrt{\lambda}=0,1/2,1,3/2,2,\cdots.
$$